# c++ overload function to compare 2 lists

Tags: c++, list, overloading

I want to overload the < operator

They are 2 lists of ints that need comparing

They are used to contain a number eg. 2526 each int as an element in the list

So I know i need to check each element from front to back to see if it's larger

But when I create an iterator `std::list<Digit>::iterator lhs = this->list1.begin;`

I can't compare the 2 iterators, bit stumped but im probably just missing something obvious at the moment this is what it looks like:

digits is a list of ints.

```
bool Integer::operator<(const Integer & rhs) const
{

    std::list<Digit>::iterator lhs = this->digits.begin;
    std::list<Digit>::iterator rhs = rhs.digits.begin;

    if (this->digits.size() < rhs.digits.size()) //lhs smaller length
    { 
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;                           //lhs larger 
    }

    if (this->digits.begin < rhs.digits.begin)  //first lhs digit lower
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (this->digits.begin > rhs.digits.begin) //first rhs digit lower
    {
        return false;
    }



    return false;
}
```

I also read about maybe using std::mismatch but no sure how to use that either

Comment: You need to dereference the iterators. Otherwise you 're comparing pointers and not actual values.

Comment: Also, `begin()` is a function.

Comment: `std::list` already have `operator <`, you just need `return digits < rhs.digits;`